# Why do we need to compare keys from different table?

Tags: mysql-5.6

can you please help me make sense of this code?

The **question**: is to find the pair of students who have registered for the same course in the same semester.

- why do I need to check the `s1.sid = r1.sid` ?
- Why can't I just the SID in registration table? I know this gives me duplicates, but I don't understand the reason behind.

My understanding behind querying tables to get results is relatively weak, please pardon me if I am asking a fundamental questions :) thanks for helping!

```
    select s1.sname, s2.sname, cname, r1.semester
    from student s1, student s2, registration r1, registration r2, course c
    where s1.sid = r1.sid and s2.sid = r2.sid 
    and r1.cid = r2.cid and r1.semester = r2.semester 
    and r1.cid = c.cid and s1.sid < s2.sid;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the student and registration? Are these tables? I used to plural 's': student_s_, table_s_, to mean a set of objects, which the tables actually are. As of not using `s.id = r.sid`, it gives you two records (objects), where one refers the other. I guess that r.sid is a foreign key, referencing a student. You then check if two registrations are for the same course at the same semester, then you select that course. By `s1.sid < s2.sid`, you exclude the same student (which obviously always takes courses with himself) and also exclude duplicates. The duplicates appear because `select s1 from students` and `select s2 from studentds` gives you all pairs of students, which means that both `('Joe Bull', 'Sarah The Terrible')` and `('Sarah The Terrible', 'Joe Bull')` show up. Why duplication in this case?

As of `why to check s1.sid = r1.sid` [look at the CROSS JOIN (aka Cartesian product) filtered with WHERE clause and INNER JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)). It turns out to be the same thing.

I also believed that there is a computational difference between taking Cartesian product and then filtering it with `where` but [it turns out that modern SQL servers realize that it is just and a join operation and accomplish it in linear N+M time rather than N*M time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins).